# Postgres best way to delete duplicates in large table with no primary key

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I have a table that logs scan events wherein I store the first and last event. Each night at midnight the all the scan events from the previous day are added to the table, duplicates are dropped, and a query is run to delete anything other than the scan event with the minimum and maximum timestamp.

One of the problems is that the data provider recycles scan ID's every 45 days, so this table does not have a primary key. Here is an example of what the table looks like in it's final state:

```
|scaneventID|scandatetime       |status   |scanfacilityzip|
+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------------+
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 13:45:12|Intake   |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-03 19:32:18|Processed|45867          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 10:24:16|Intake   |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-02 02:15:52|Processed|84676          |
```

But before the cleanup queries are run it can look like this:

```
|scaneventID|scandatetime       |status   |scanfacilityzip|
+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------------+
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 13:45:12|Intake   |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 13:45:12|Intake   |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 19:30:32|Received |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-02 04:50:22|Confirmed|12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-03 19:32:18|Processed|45867          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 10:24:16|Intake   |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 19:30:32|Received |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 19:30:32|Received |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-02 02:15:52|Processed|84676          |
```

Because there are sometimes data overlap from the vendor and there's nothing we can really do about that. I currently run the following queries to delete duplicates:

```
DELETE   FROM scans T1
  USING       scans T2
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM current_timestamp-T1.scandatetime) < 2
  AND  T1.ctid   < T2.ctid
  AND  T1.scaneventID    = T2.scaneventID
  AND  T1.scandatetime = T2.scandatetime
;
```

And to retain only the min/max timestamps:

```
delete from scans
    where EXTRACT(DAY FROM current_timestamp-scandatetime) < 2 and
          scandatetime <> (select min(tt.scandatetime) from scans tt where tt.scaneventID = scans.scaneventID) and
          scandatetime <> (select max(tt.scandatetime) from scans tt where tt.scaneventID = scans.scaneventID)
;
```

However the table is quite large (100's of millions of scans over multiple years) so these run quite slowly. How can I speed this up?

Comment: Are there any indexes on the table? If not, is adding them an option? An index on scandatetime should help, especially if you change that EXTRACT to something like `WHERE scandatetime>(current_timestamp - interval '2 days')` to let it take advantage of  the index to only look at the most recent entries.

Comment: Yes, there are several indexes on the table. On `scaneventID` and `scandatetime` as well as a few others that are not pertinent to this query. I can try updating the timestamp clause to what you have suggested, that could be a boost

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what you have linked is basically what I'm doing?

Comment: `scandatetime <> (select min(tt.scandatetime) from scans tt ...` <<-- I would not do this. Instead, use an `EXISTS(...) AND EXISTS(...)`

Comment: @wildplasser if you submit an answer I will gladly accept!